# The proper way to download files from iCloud

Tags: swift, xcode, icloud

I have been trying to implement the iCloud backup feature in my app. Some Stack Overflow answers and other websites said that the following method would work. However, the following code doesn't work sometimes. The download progress is either fixed at 0%, or it says 100% but the file is still an outdated local copy.

```swift
func download(itemUrl: URL) {
    // Remove the local copy of the item
    try? FileManager.default.evictUbiquitousItem(at: itemUrl)

    // Request iCloud to start downloading the item
    try? FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: itemUrl)

    // Watch for item status change
    // Create metadata query to observe:
    // 1. The path of the file item
    // 2. The download progress of the file item
    let metadataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
    metadataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope, NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]
    metadataQuery.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
            NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, itemUrl.path),
            NSPredicate(format: "%K >= 0", NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey)
    ])

    // Called when the query result is updated
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object: metadataQuery, queue: nil, using: { notification in
        self.updateDownloadProgress(notification)
    })

    // Called when the query is finished
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: metadataQuery, queue: nil, using: { notification in
        self.updateDownloadProgress(notification)
    })

    // Start the query
    metadataQuery.start()
}
```

and the `updateDownloadProgress` function:

```swift
func updateDownloadProgress(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Get download progress (%),
    // Stop the query when the progress reaches 100%
}
```

Error handlings are omitted. I'm assuming that there is a request limit per minute or per hour in iCloud, which is blocking this method from always working as I intend. What changes should I make to make this work 100% of the time? Any help will be appreciated.

Update: Is this issue related to the fact that I'm not using `NSFileCoordinator`?

Comment: When you say 'iCloud Backup' I presume you don't mean the system feature 'iCloud Backup' but a means of backing up app data in the Apps icloud container?

Comment: `NSMetaDataQuery` is what is required to initiate iCloud updates. What you do afterwards with the file (such as using `NSFileCoordinator`) shouldn't affect the download function. With regards to issues with your code - I'm sorry I'm unable to comment. I would follow the directions in Discovering an App's Documents in [Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW1)